# Multiple Form Validation - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate a form field in laravel **mb_plans** based on 2 others form fields **activity** and **options**, if both **activity** and **options** have there respective value then validate **mb_plans**

I've tried required_if and required_with, but can't able to use AND condition.

```
'mb_plans' => 'required_if:activity,MB|required_with:options,0',
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate when activity value is MB and options is 0 then use :

```
'mb_plans' => 'required_if:activity,==,MB|required_if:options,==,0',
```

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
'mb_plans' => 'required_with_all:activity,options',
```

Comment: How do I check activity value is MB or not? I have many activity values. It should only validate with MB

Comment: try with `'mb_plans' => ['required_if:activity,MB', 'required_if:options,0']`